# How do I get the caption text of the jQuery to align with the image?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm having a problem with [carousel](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel). I would like to make the caption the same width as the image but just now it is set to the same width as the inner item class.

I get the following effect:

[image]

Is there a way to set the caption so it is centred (and aligned with the image)?

My markup is:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">
      <div class="inner-item">
        <img src="img/1.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>Caption</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="inner-item">
        <img src="img/1.jpg">
      </div>
       <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>Caption text here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="inner-item">
        <img src="img/1.jpg">
      </div>
       <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>Caption text here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide a fiddle

Comment: This looks to be an issue with the `.carousel-caption` CSS. Which you have not provided.

Comment: @vletech this css class is provided by http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly 
Why you don't use `text-align:center;`  for the caption and change the width to the image's width

```
.carousel-caption
{
    text-align:center;
    width:800px; 
    /*If you are having aligning problems and the position is absolute or relative use left:some_number px or margin if not absolute */ 

}
```

I hope this can help :)

Comment: Sorry, that only makes the caption large and aligns the text within it.

Comment: You need to make it in the center , and change the width

Comment: @Sheldon, remove the height from the CSS sorry

Comment: Hey @Sedz, I get what you're trying to do but that only aligns text withing the carousel-caption. I want to align the carousel caption element.